# How to return a string while my method is returning ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, return-value

I have a method which returns ArrayList type but I have a try/throw/catch block which does the exception handling. If fail, I would like to return a string saying that it failed.

Example of my code here

```
public ArrayList<test> testing
{
    try
    {
        Arraylist<test> arr = new ArrayList();
        return arr

    } catch (exception e) {
           return "Failed";
    }
}
```

Above is just example of what I want to do. What is want is when it succeed, it will return the ArrayList which is okay. But when failed, it will return a string. How can I do it? It is possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Java is a strongly typed language. Since you declared that your method returns `ArrayList` you have to return just that or `null`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your idea seems unsound and in fact impossible since after all, a method can only and **should only** return one single type. You should consider throwing an exception (my preference), or returning null as a marker (not as good I think since it's less informative).

i.e.,

```
public ArrayList<test> testing throws SomeException {
    Arraylist<test> arr = new ArrayList();
    if (somethingFails) { 
      String message = "an explanation of why the method failed";
      throw new SomeException(message);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to return a string in case of an exception, what you should do is `throw` your own exception type, which would indicate that a failure had occurred (google how to create custom exceptions). Whatever is calling this method needs to be enclosed in its own try-catch block with catch filtering your custom exception first. If that catch block fires, you know a failure has occurred.